# Graphs with prescribed numbers of k-cliques

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n)$ be a sequence of non-negative integers.

**Q.** When does there exists a simple graph $G$ such that its number of $k$-cliques is $a_k$ (that is $G$ has $a_1$ vertices, $a_2$ edges, $a_3$ trinagles, etc)?

Probably, it is hopeless to get a complete description of such sequences, so I am interested in any necessary or sufficient conditions on $\{a_i\}$.

**Upd.** As Steve Huntsman mentions in the comments there are trivial necessary conditions: $a_k\le \binom{a_0}{k}$. There are also more complicated inequalities like 
$$
\binom{a_1}{3}-a_3\le \bigl(\binom{a_1}{2}-a_2\bigr)(a_1-2).
$$

Comment: There are trivial necessary conditions $a_k \le \binom{a_0}{k+1}$

Comment: @SteveHuntsman Yes, sure. There are also not that trivial, e.g., $\binom{a_0}{3}-a_2\le (\binom{a_0}{2}-a_1)(a_0-2)$ (the number of non-triangles is less or equal the number of non-edges times $a_0-2$)

Comment: Nice question. A $k$-clique is normally defined as a clique with $k$ vertices, so you should probably adjust your indexing.

Comment: @Tony Thanks! Yes, my bad. I updated the notation.

Comment: @DanielSoltész Yes, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Is $G$ allowed to have cliques of size larger than $n$? In my answer I have assumed that it cannot, so $a_i=0$ for $i > n$ (I guess that just seemed natural to me). After rereading your question I now feel that may not have been intention.

Comment: @JohnMachacek Initially I was also assuming that $a_i=0$ for $i>n$. However, I am interested in the answer in the case you mentioned (i.e. no restrictions on the number of $k$-cliques of $G$ for $k>n$) as well. (It seems Kruskal-Katona Theorem is still working here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking for is possible $f$-vectors of [Clique Complexes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex). The [Kruskal-Katona Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Katona_theorem) characterizes $f$-vectors of simplicial complexes; so, it applies here but is no longer a complete characterization. Your problem is open according to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6210.pdf). The linked paper and references there in contain partial results.

**Edit:** This answer assumes the number of $k$-cliques of $G$ is $a_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $0$ for $k > n$. Another interpretation of the question would be that the number of $k$-cliques of $G$ is $a_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and there is no restriction on the number of $k$-cliques for $k > n$. The OP has expressed interest in both variations in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the linked paper. I have looked at the references in it and they mostly answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

The case $n=3$ was addressed in Razborov's [*On the Minimal Density of Triangles in Graphs*](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/files/triangles.pdf), where he used his Flag Algebra technique to provide an asymptotically tight lower bound on the number of triangles contained in a graph with a given number of vertices and edges.

Let $\rho=\frac{a_2}{\binom{a_1}{2}}$ be the density of edges in the graph. If $\rho=1-\frac{1}{t}$ for some integer $t$, then the minimum number of triangles comes from a balanced, complete $t$-partite graph.  If $\rho \in (1-\frac{1}{t}, 1-\frac{1}{t+1})$, then the optimal graph ends up being a complete $(t+1)$-partite graph, with $t$ equal sized parts, and one part smaller than the rest.  Optimizing over the size of the parts gives the (complicated) bound in Razborov's paper.